# How has_iterator is working in given code?

Tags: c++11, templates, type-traits

Please consider below program:

```
    template <typename T>
    struct has_iterator
    {
        template <typename U>
        static char test(typename U::iterator* x);

        template <typename U>
        static long test(U* x);

        static constexpr const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;
    };

    int main() {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_iterator<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The output of the above program is true. Here my question is when T is `std::vector<int>` why `static char test(typename U::iterator* x)` is preferred over `static long test(U* x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started off the right way. After template argument substitution has taken place, overload resolution is left to pick between

```
static char test<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>::iterator* x);
```

and

```
static long test<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>* x);
```

It makes sense to think this would be ambiguous. `0` is equally convertible to either pointer type.

The reason this still works is simply because overload resolution has a tiebreaker, where a more specialised function template is preferred over a more generic function template. The first function template is more specialised.

Comment: As per my understanding after template argument substitution we will have following 2 overloads: `static char test<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>::iterator* x);` and `static long test<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>* x);`. I fail to see, how we have this overload `static long test<std::vector<int>::iterator>(std::vector<int>::iterator* x);`, as T is `std::vector<int>` not `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Can you please explain. Thank you.

Comment: @Sajal Whoops. You're right about that, I messed up. Edited, thanks for the correction.